Terraform | AWS Cognito | How to set Federated Identity Provider's `Idp-initiated SAML sign-in`?
I am working on terraforming my AWS Cognito User Pools, but my google-fu is failing me. How do I configure my federated identity provider so that it's IdP-initiated SAML sign-in is assigned to Require SP-initiated SAML assertions?

AWS Cognito doesn't natively enforce SP-initiated SAML assertions for IdP-initiated logins. You can mitigate this by using custom AWS Lambda triggers (Pre-Token Generation) or AWS WAF rules to manage access flows. Here's a basic Terraform setup for SAML IdP:
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_identity_provider" "saml_idp" {
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.example.id
  provider_name = "YourSAMLProvider"
  provider_type = "SAML"
  provider_details = {
    MetadataFile = "saml-metadata.xml"
  }
}

Use Lambda for deeper control.

I can control the setting it via the console though
